# Tricky NOT NULL error django utils Integrity error

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tricky NULL Constraint error.
Previously working when i just delete py and pyc files from migrations folder. now when i make migrations it is no longer working.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Htweets2_htweets2.tweet_location
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Htweets2(models.Model):
    tweet_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    tweet_timestamp = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    tweet_screenname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    tweet_favour_count = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    tweet_recount = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    tweet_location = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    tweet_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tweet_media_entities = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

from my views.py, i am trying to save to a table that doesnt exists

```
e = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

tweets = Htweets2()
for x in e:
    tweets.tweet_timestamp = x['timestamp_ms']
    tweets.tweet_id = x['id']
    tweets.tweet_screename = x['user']['screen_name']
    tweets.tweet_recount = x['retweet_count']
    tweets.tweet_favour_count = x['favorite_count']
    tweets.tweet_text = x['text']
    tweets.tweet_location = x['user']['location']
    tweets.tweet_media_entities = x['source']

tweets.save()
```

But surely when i make migrate, django should create a new table wouldnt it?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
 File "/home/hermes/Documents/Htweetprod2/Htweetprod2/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
from Htweets2 import views
 File "/home/hermes/Documents/Htweetprod2/Htweets2/views.py", line 24, in <module>
tweets.save()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Htweets2_htweets2
```

I am certain that simply deleting pyc and py files from migrations folder was working, but after i have done it several times, it does not longer make me do makemigrations.

Comment: Why do you have `default=None` and `null=True` for the `CharField`? The typical approach in Django is to have `default=''` and `null=False`, which would avoid the integrity error. It looks as if you are missing a migration to allow nulls on the `tweet_location` column, but you haven't provided enough information to debug further.

Comment: hi i have just altered to default = '' and null = False. It is still giving an Integrity error. Is it because of the Charfield?

Comment: After changing the values, you will have to create a migration and then run it. You might want to change your other fields that have `default=None` at the same time. Note that you don't have to include `default='', null=True` in the field definition, because those are the defaults. You still want `blank=True`, otherwise the Django admin will not accept empty values.

Comment: create a migration you mean manage.py makemigrations? and i did what u have asked, tweet_location and just left blank=True on everything however tweet_location is till giving intergrity error

Comment: Yes, I mean make a migration with `makemigrations` then run the migration with `migrate`.

Comment: I just noticed you said that you deleted your migrations files. That's a really bad idea, it means that your migration files and your database are out of sync. If you don't have important data in the database, then I recommend you drop the database, delete the migration files then run makemigrations and migrate again. If you do have important data in the database, then syncing up the migrations with the database might be very tricky, and I'm afraid I can't help with that.

Comment: yep :( when i make migrate , django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Htweets2_htweets2.tweet_location
and made all fields blank = True

Comment: yes i deleted the migrations files execept __init__.py when droprring the database, does that mean i have to go to the shell and drop the database their?

Comment: You don't have to remove the `migrations/__init__.py`. The instructions for how to drop the database depend on which database you are using. In your case, you can simply remove the sqlite file (or rename it if you need the data), and Django will create a new one when you run migrate.

Comment: owe so, i have a file called db.sqlite3, your saying i should delete that?

Comment: Either rename the `db.sqlite3` file if the database contains any important data, or delete it if you don't need it any more.

Comment: hi i deleted the database and i tried to makemigrations. but i have this error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Htweets2_htweets2

Comment: That error isn't enough to solve the problem. You need to show the full traceback, and the code that is causing the error. Please [edit] your question, and don't paste code or tracebacks in the comments.

Comment: Hi, i edited the question as requested

Comment: Something in your views is trying to save to the database when the views are loaded, before migrate has created the table. You haven't shown the full traceback so we can't tell what that is.

Comment: hi sorry, yep i have added the traceback now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading the json and saving the tweets *every* time the module is imported. This causes an error when the database is first created, because migrate has not created the database tables yet. You should move this code into a function, for example:

```
def load_tweets():

    e = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

    tweets = Htweets2()
    for x in e:
        tweets.tweet_timestamp = x['timestamp_ms']
        ...
        tweets.save()
```

Comment: just a quick question because i deleted the database will i need to create a new superuser?

Comment: Yes -- the details for any old users were in the database that you deleted.